# Finding certain pattern inside a list using for statement

Tags: python

I am having a bit of troubles getting this part of my code to work, I need to find a way to count the amount of times than an H occurs in a row in a list, (H, H, H) would count as two occurrences. I feel like I'm getting somewhere but just can't get the j to count up.

```
list['H', 'H', 'T', 'H']
j = 0
n = 0
for letter in list:
    if list[n] == ['H'] and list[n+1] == ['H']:
        j = j + 1

print('it was this amount of times ' + str(j))
```

Comment: Please edit your question with clarification. How does `[h, h, h]` not count as 3 occurrences?

Comment: seems your code counts how many times H occurs consecutive. Look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Comment: sorry I should be more clear, I am looking for an occurrence in the list where [ H, H] occurs so in other words, I am looking for H to occur back to back and count how many times this occurs

Comment: What do you expect the count for this list : `['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H']`? 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex for this:

```
len(re.findall("H(?=H)", "HHH"))
```

The trick is using lookahead to match the second `H`, but still allow it to be matched again.

Before you think "regex is overkill for this and hard to read," two counter variables, indexing, and math has a lot more places for something to go wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I would also suggest a regex, however the title says 'for loop'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list= ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H']
j = 0
n = 0
for letter in list:
    if letter == 'H' and list[n+1] == 'H':
        j = j + 1

print('it was this amount of times ' + str(j))
```

Will give

```
it was this amount of times 3
```

Comment: `n+1` will always check the second element in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get how ('H', 'H', 'H') counted to 2, is it that you want to find how many consecutive H occurs after first H?
Try out this, just updated few parts of your code:

```
data = ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H']
j = 0

for index in range(len(data)-1):
    if data[index] == 'H' and data[index+1] == 'H':
        j = j + 1

print('it was this amount of times ' + str(j))
```

Output:

```
it was this amount of times 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something clever with `zip` and `sum`:

```
>>> data = ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T']
>>> sum(a == b == 'H' for a, b in zip(data[1:], data[:-1]))
3
```

Same thing with an index:

```
sum(data[i-1] == data[i] == 'H' for i in range(1, len(data)))
```